# opencl - using image multiple times

Tags: c, go, opencl

So I want to make a app that shows some images and when the window resizes, it scales also all images to fit on the screen.
My strategy is this:

1. call clCreateImage for every original image and store the `cl_mem` pointers in a global map (something like: `filename -> cl_mem`)
2. call `scale(cl_mem img, int width, int height)`, that calls a kernel and reads the output image data. Then show the scaled images.
3. when the a window resize event occures: drop all scaled images and call `scale(...)` another time, with the `cl_mem` pointers stored in the map

I tried it on a small scale where I just create one image, and call `scale` two times. The first is OK and scaled, but the second is corrupted. I don't know why, the src image is `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`, the out image is created in `scale` function.

original: https://ibb.co/pQDwScW

first time scaled (to fit in 300x300): https://ibb.co/nnN9kTY

second try (to fit in 500x500): https://ibb.co/561SkSn

But also when I try just 300x300 and then also 300x300 it is corrupted.
Is there a rule, that images can't be used in a kernel multiple times? Or im just missing something?

**EDIT:**

C code is here: https://pastebin.com/NpSaxRyT

It is used from golang with cgo, so the `createImage` returns the `cl_mem` as `void*`, so that the Go part doesn't need to include `cl.h`.

`init()` function is called on startup of the Go program. `createImage` function is called from Go with pixel data.

So the image pointers (`cl_mem` pointers) are in Go and then the `resize` (`scale`) function is called. It takes the `void*` pointer and buffer pointer where the pixel data will be transfered.
Also the buffer is allocated by Go, but with the first image it is OK and I think that the GC doesn't kick in (also tried to disable GC entirely).

like so:

```golang
    outData := make([]byte, outWidth*outHeight*ir.pixelSize)
    ret := C.resize(
        cl_mem_img_pointer, //unsafe.Pointer (void*)
        C.int(origWidth),
        C.int(origHeight),
        C.int(outWidth),
        C.int(outHeight),
        C.int(rowPitch),
        C.uint(image_channel_order),
        C.uint(image_channel_data_type),
        unsafe.Pointer(&outData[0]),
    )
```

Comment: Are you calling the two C.resize functions in same thread one after another? Some opencl commands like clSetKernelArg are not thread-safe when they have same kernel name.

Comment: It can be that go is swapping main with GC thread. How can I give them different names. Also why is that the first kernel is created, run, and released. And the second kernel a completly new one. Or isn't it that the img is created in one thread and kernel is created in the other? EDIT: I tried `runtime.LockOSThread()` and the results are the same.

Comment: " the results are the same" what does this mean? 2 resizes work same succssfully? Or it is the same corruption? You don't need to re-create everything. Just re-use kernel for all operations and only release once before you exit your program. Same for images too. If you already have same sized output image, you can re-use it. Just release once before program exits or free RAM is decreasing too much. Why LockOSThread? Is this to negate GoRoutine? 2 scalings in different Goroutines must be problem then.

Comment: The same - like corrupted second try. So I can have one global kernel and just set clSetKernelArg when running it?

Comment: Created a repository https://git.sr.ht/~ghost08/clir/tree
Please check it, now it segfaults on clSetKernelArg when running the second time. When you have gcc, golang and opencl installed, just run `go test`.

Comment: On which clSetKernelArg does it segfault? 2? 2.1? 2.2? 2.3? What error code? https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/clSetKernelArg.html here you see error code list.

Comment: 2.1 isn't printed, and no error code, just crash: https://pastebin.com/J1v2ZR3K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are releasing right after the first resize operation

```
if err := ir.Release(); err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}

img2, err := ir.Resize(200, 200)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
```

and the 200x200 resize failes as it can not find the img component that was released.

All of OpenCL objects are re-usable until you exit the program. Before exiting, just don't forget to release the resources in the reverse-order they were allocated.

If you are using only same kernel for all tasks, you can use just one global kernel object to be used for all resize calls. It only needs re-setting kernel arguments which are changed between calls. For example, changing sizes of output image, image buffer itself, etc.

Comment: Oh this was awkward. Such a stupid error. Thank you very much! I will use one kernel for every image, because it will be used in multiple threads.

Comment: Does it also solve corruption?

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly. I try it also in multiple go routines.

Comment: For multiple threads using same kernel, better sync during setkernelarg command as its not threadsafe or just use different kernel instances or even program instances. Just different kernel instances should be enough for multithread.